# IntelliJ IDEA 11 adding CDI facet fails?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, cdi

I have the follwing dependencies in my POM. I am trying to add the CDI facet in IntelliJ IDEA 11 because I thought I would get an option for creating the beans.xml file without manually having to write it, just as you do with persistence.xml etc. However even though I have the dependencies it says Weld is missing, but why do I need to download these when I have everything I  need in the POM?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a JBoss stack, I usually use that dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.Final</version>
<type>pom</type>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

(Requires JBoss Repo)

Have a look at that configuration [here](https://github.com/jangroth/jax2011/blob/master/todo/pom.xml), which I used for a plain Java EE 6 stack (on a JBoss AS 6)

Answer (score 0):

I've never had weld on the classpath. Simply the cdi-api and the beans.xml and it finds the facet just fine. If you're worried about having to manually create the beans.xml, create a template for it and be done.